# holy grail/ right div floating under

Tags: css, divide

I've been trying to figure out what my right div is floating out of position.

```css
.header{
 background:red;
 height:100px;
 width:100%;
}

.left{
 background:white;
 float:left;
 height:800px;
 width: 200px;
}

.main{
 background:yellow;
 height: 800px;
 width: 600px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.right{
 background:white;
 float: right;
 height:800px;
 width: 200px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.footer{
 background:red;
 height: 100px;
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/> 
</head> 
<title>Layout</title> 
<body> 
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Any pointers? I know this is going to be deceptively simple but I've drawn a blank

Comment: Somthing like this? http://jsfiddle.net/dowomentfart/0r6nhr34/

Comment: It's a little easier if you use colors other than white - http://jsfiddle.net/wahh853v/2/ Your main div should be floated too...Note...becase of the widths you have you may need to expand the fiddle window. Oh...and clear the floats.

Comment: ahh, yes, clear the floats. thanks1 :)

Comment: Clearing the floats is one thing, but the template you are using is very rigid. Take a look at my answer for a more flexible solution that will lend itself well to responsive design principles down the line (such as sliding in sidebar menus, or just supporting smaller resolutions).

Answer (score -1):

```css
div{
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 margin:3px;
}

.header{
    background:red;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
}

.left{
    background:white;
    float:left;
    height:800px;
    width: 200px;
}

.main{
    background:yellow;
    height: 800px;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.right{
    background:white;
    float: right;
    height:800px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.footer{
    background:red;
    height: 100px;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
    <div class="main">main</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
```

This is the correct way :

first put the floating elements (left - right) than the non floating one (main)

Also make shure you clear after float ("clear:both")

ps I give thhe main "with:auto" but is not necessary... only more compatible

```
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
    <div class="main">main</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
```

Comment: You do not need the extra clear elements in there. There are many other ways to clear the floats that would be much more flexible for a responsive design than having hard elements in there. The content should always be ordered semantically, especially when we are talking about the layout for an entire page. Usually this means the main content first, than the sidebar content. Additionally, your CSS has general room for improvement for brevity and to be optimized.

Comment: yes Matthew. Tut this is the layout proposed in the question. the clear divs are very good  for compatibility with older browser. and it solve the question.

Comment: The clear divs are completely unnecessary for compatibility, you could easily add the clear styles to .left and .footer. Adding extra HTML elements with inline styles is NEVER a best practice if it can be avoided, especially when you are trying to accomplish something visually that is completely unrelated to the content.

Answer (score -1):

Semantically, you probably should go with the main content of the page first, then the supporting content. This template also will shrink the content area based on the space available, although that can easily be adjusted with the CSS if you wanted a fixed layout by setting a specific width on the `.content` element.

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="main-inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Then for the CSS, you use something like this:

```
.header, .footer, .content {
    clear: both;
}
.header, .footer {
    height: 100px;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px; /* Keeps the site from growing beyond 1000px */
    margin: 0 auto; /* Centers the content area */
}
.main, .left, .right {
    float: left;
}
.main {
    width: 100%;
}
.main-inner {
    margin: 0 200px;
}
.left, .right {
    width: 200px;
}
.left {
    margin-left: -100%; /* Puts the left sidebar to the top left of the .content element */
}
.right {
    margin-left: -200px; /* Puts the right sidebar on the right edge of the .content element */
}

/* Colors and Heights so you can see things */
.main-inner, .left, .right { min-height:600px; }
.header, .footer { background-color: red; }
.main-inner { background-color: yellow; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j1rLfmky/